# Requesting Curl request with headers

Tags: php, http, php-curl

Am new to curl i want to send curl request with header using the follow structure

```
$ curl -H 'X-API-Key: INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE'           \
       -F 'image_url=https://www.remove.bg/example.jpg'   \
       -F 'size=auto'                                     \
       -f https://api.remove.bg/v1.0/removebg -o no-bg.png
```

Here is the code am using

```
function cUrl($url, $post_fields = null, $headers = null) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            $timeout = 5;
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            if ($post_fields && !empty($post_fields)) {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
            }
            if ($headers && !empty($headers)) {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            }
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            if (curl_errno($ch)) {
                echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
            }
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
        }
$url = "https://api.remove.bg/v1.0/removebg";
    $post_fields = 'image_url=https://example.com/1.png&size=auto';
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'X-API-Key'=>'1234567890'
        );
    $data = $bg->cUrl($url, $post_fields, $headers);
```

and this is what am getting

> {"errors":[{"title":"Missing API
>   Key","code":"auth_failed","detail":"Please provide your API key via
>   the X-Api-Key request header"}]}

How do i send this request?

Comment: The array should just be an array of strings, not key=>value pairs

Comment: As mentioned, your entry would be something like `"x-api-key: your-api-key”,`

Comment: `$headers = array('apikey');` same error

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'X-Api-Key: api-key'
)); didn't work